# Target is configured multiple times errors when trying to update

Tags: apt, updates

```
Fetched 44.6 MB in 9min 28s (78.4 kB/s)                                                                                                       
Reading package lists... Done
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list:67
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list:67
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list:67
W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list:67
W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list:67
W: Target DEP-11 (partner/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list:67
W: Target DEP-11-icons (partner/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list:67
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:55 and /etc/apt/sources.list:69
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:55 and /etc/apt/sources.list:69
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:55 and /etc/apt/sources.list:69
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:55 and /etc/apt/sources.list:69
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:55 and /etc/apt/sources.list:69
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:55 and /etc/apt/sources.list:69
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:55 and /etc/apt/sources.list:69
W: http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg: Signature by key C47415DFF48C09645B78609416126D3A3E5C1192 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list:67
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list:67
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list:67
W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list:67
W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list:67
W: Target DEP-11 (partner/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list:67
W: Target DEP-11-icons (partner/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list:67
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:55 and /etc/apt/sources.list:69
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:55 and /etc/apt/sources.list:69
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:55 and /etc/apt/sources.list:69
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:55 and /etc/apt/sources.list:69
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:55 and /etc/apt/sources.list:69
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:55 and /etc/apt/sources.list:69
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:55 and /etc/apt/sources.list:69
```

Comment: Check /etc/apt/sources.list.

Answer (score 0):

First of all lets back up sources.list. This is always a good idea when doing anything that influences this file.

`sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.backup`

To be extra safe we'll edit a copy of sources.list in our home folder.

We copy sources.list and make sure we are in our home directory :

`cp /etc/apt/sources.list ~/ ; cd ~`

Awk is a powerful Unix command. I don't understand it very well, but you can always read up on it.

Then we'll use awk to remove the duplicate lines :

`awk '!x[$0]++' sources.list > sources-revised.list`

We'll check that everything looks alright :

`more sources-revised.list`

We'll copy it back :

`sudo cp sources-revised.list /etc/apt/sources.list`

We'll update :

`sudo apt-get update`

Thanks to Jadu Saikia for the [awk knowledge](http://www.unixcl.com/2008/03/remove-duplicates-without-sorting-file.html)

Comment: This approach made no difference for me.

Comment: did the awk command remove the duplicates? what did you see at the step `more sources-revised.list`?

Comment: There are no duplicates in my sources.list file, but I'm still seeing the "configured multiple times" messages.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu and apt are you running? If both versions are supported you may want to 'Report a bug' --> https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt